# Keyboard problem with Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, keyboard

I have an international keyboard, and my customized my layout so that the letters P and O and I are written, when I type the keys on which there are my national(country) letters painted on. I have this custom layout because I my normal P O and I keys are unresponsive(broken), and since I literally never use my country national letters, I used a windows keyboard mapper to remap the keys, so I can type P O and I again. The problem is because Skyrim, whenever I type P O and I, instead of accepting P O and I, it accepts the keys which would be input if I still had my normal natiional keyboard layout, but I dont, I customized it. All the other games accept my customized windows keyboard layout, but for some reason skyrim does not. Skyrim when I type O, I and P it ignores my custom keyboard layout and it just types Æ È Ø... now, all the other games, multiplayer and singleplayer, all games recognise my custom windows keyboard, so that when i press Æ they read P and when I press Ø they read I and when I press È they read O, but Skyrim doesnt read that..in Skyrim when I press the keys Æ È Ø skyrim types Æ È Ø instead of P I O ,,,

How do I make Skyrim read my custom windows keyboard layout that i customized with a program called ''Microsoft keyboard layout creator''

And dont say ''buy new keyboard'' because this keyboards works awesome and I can use everything i need and type everything i need, they keys O P I have been broken for 2 years and ive been working with the remapped layout just great for 2 years and the others games accept it but this is the first time ive encountered a problem. **Why doesnt skyrim read my custom windows keyboard layout and how do i make it read it?**

*PS: also, i noticed if i press CTRL + V, it wont paste the letters into the window where im trying to type my name but can't because skyrim reads Æ È Ø when I press Æ È Ø instead of reading O P I when i press Æ È Ø . Therefore, I can't create a character with O P I because Skyrim wont read the inputs.... This is the same reason I can't type console commands*

Comment: I would suggest to buy a new keyboard.

Comment: Ive been thinking, is there a way to open the savegame files? maybe i could just add the console commands to save game file? how to open .ess ?

Answer (score 5):

You could try using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) if you have some technical chops. It's not strictly a developer-only tool, though having some vague understanding of programming/scripting will make picking it up easier.

You could use it to remap whatever keys you want to whatever other key you want. It can also be used to do all sorts of macroing.

The simplest case for remapping your keyboard would look something like this:

`a:: Send, x`

This will make the `a` key send an `x` whenever it is pressed by itself. (however, holding another key with it, like Shift or Ctrl will still treat it as an `a`).

Bear in mind, I don't have an international keyboard, so YMMV.

Comment: I already did that, please read my whole post

Comment: @iLoveSkyrim Did you try AutoHotKey specifically? Your post only mentions Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator.

Comment: @iLoveSkyrim AutoHotKey is an entirely different product from Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator. Your post mentions nothing about it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason, **although not a solution** is probably because skyrim uses directinput to gather the pressed keys and at that point it means it's polling directly the keyboard and not going through the windows mapping or going through your key re-mapping.

If you press ~ in game to bring the console in and type, do you get the intended characters, if not it really means skyrim is using directinput on the keyboard. Which makes much sense cause if you want your game to be fully compatible with the XBOX, you'd have to sure direct input i think.

The real solution is to fix your keyboard and/or buy a new one. I don't think you can do anything else than that sadly...

Comment: keyboard unfixable, i wont buy a new one just because one game, skyrim, isnt compatible with my custom keyboard layout, 

here is the deal, 3 of my keys arent working. so, the 3 keys that arent working(O, P and I), i remapped those 3 keys to the keys Æ È Ø because I literally NEVER use Æ È Ø, the reason i can type Æ È Ø right now is because im copy pasting it from windows symbol program

thank you for your post tho...i guess its unfixable... but ive played many games that were for pc and xbox and ps3 and my keyboard layout worked on all of em..Skyrim is the first that cause me problem

Answer (score 1):

I've created Direct Input Paste. Simulates pasting to console with AutoHotkey. Find it [here](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=11034) at Skyrim Nexus Mods.

It also has a replacement for Alt-Tab, which means no more opening Task Manager and double Alt-Tabbing back to Skyrim, as well as a keyboard volume controller for Skyrim. It simply switches to the desktop volume slider and either increases, decreases or mutes the volume almost instantly!

Do not forget to log in and endorse the project.

Answer (score -1):

The way I solved it is to Press start -> control panel -> look for "change keyboard or input methods" (or some thing like that, I don't have the English version of Windows) -> press change keyboards -> and set English as your main keyboard.

Important to say, you'll still be able to switch languages normally with shift+alt.

Answer (score -4):

for anyone who might stumble onto this topic in the future, download a keyboard macro called ''Hot Keyboard Pro'', then in this program dont use the paste function, because then in skyrim only a 0 will apear, 
use the ''record keyboard strokes'' function, and then when u have the hot keyboard pro open you just open a notepad and click record in program, then type the console command in it, then press ctrl+break, and then it will be recorded and map it to letter U or T or whichever works, then run the game, open console, press U or T or whichever u configered it to and then sit back and the recorded keystrokes will appear

YOU HAVE TO HAVE SKYRIM CLOSED when u do this tho, do it in windows with microsoft keyboard layout program turned on, thats how itll transfer properly!